How can I use the primary clipboard in a terminal emulator under Wayland?
When running vim in a terminal emulator under X11, any text selected in visual mode would be added to the primary clipboard, as expected. In addition, manually using the * register would also work.
In Wayland, this no longer works. Neither selected text nor the * register modify the primary clipboard. (The normal + clipboard works.)
I have tested using the terminator emulator and KDE's default Konsole emulator. OTOH the primary clipboard works in Gvim. Is it possible to get the primary clipboard working for vim in a terminal emulator under Wayland?
A partial workaround might involve remapping *y to wl-copy --primary, but I'd really like text selected in visual mode automatically added to the primary clipboard. Any workaround that achieves this would be perfect.
I'm running an up-to-date KDE Plasma 6.1.4, up-to-date vim 9.1.0672, on Arch Linux. I'm using the gvim compilation, i.e. with +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard support.

There’s been some discussion of Wayland on the mailing list and GitHub; maybe there’s something extra to do for clipboard support? Might be worth searching to see what turns up

Thanks @D.BenKnoble. I had a look at the mailing list and GitHub, and the only thing I could find was this issue that mainly focuses on the lack of support of the normal + clipboard (although this works for me). There is only peripheral mention of the primary * register. Presumably this is just unsupported at the moment. I've edited the question to include discussion of workarounds.

"Autoselect" feature (:h 'go-a') is only in GVim. Please, note that Visual mode in Vim and "select in terminal" are two different things.

Thanks @Matt, that looks exactly like what I want, but unfortunately as you say it's only in GVim. The strange things is that it worked in my terminal emulator under X11 previously. Perhaps it's a bug in the various terminal emulators instead. (I think I understand the difference, presuming that by "select in terminal" you mean clicking the mouse in a way that is independent of vim. For my terminal I hold shift.)

An extra hacky hack might abuse cursorhold and mode() to write the selection to * during a pause with  text visually selected?

Thanks again @D.BenKnoble, interesting idea. Unfortunately cursorhold doesn't seem to be available for visual mode. cursormoved might work, but would maybe trigger too frequently.
